# Cron Job - Dreamhost

Tags: php, cron, dreamhost

I currently have a cron job setup using the DreamHost control panel.

This runs without any issues, i am know trying to save the output to a file.

i have tried the following in the control panel:

```
/usr/bin/php/test/carmun15/website/index.php > /usr/bin/php/home/test/website/index1.php 2>&1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some spaces in the example you provided, you are also attempting to write to a location which you won't be able to write to.

Here is what I am guessing it should be ...

```
/usr/bin/php /home/carmun15/website/index.php > /home/carmun15/website/index1.php 2>&1
```

You need to check your paths and make sure everything is correct

`/usr/bin/php` - path to php

`/home/carmun15/website/index.php` - path to the script you want to run

`/home/carmun15/website/index1.php` - path to your log file